# What is the Oracle equivalent of SQL Server credential

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Environment : Oracle 12C

In SQL Server, a credential is a record that contains the authentication information (credentials) required to connect to a resource outside SQL Server. This information is used internally by SQL Server. Most credentials contain a Windows user name and password.Here is Microsoft doc about [Credentials in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/credentials-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) .In SQL Server, the default is to use the service account credentials to access the resource outside SQL Server. 
What is the SQL Server credential equivalent in Oracle ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalence as it depends on the resource.

For database links (which are equivalent to SQL Server linked servers), credentials are not stored as a separate object but are considered as part of the [database link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-DATABASE-LINK.html#GUID-D966642A-B19E-449D-9968-1121AF06D793) itself.

For local external jobs, remote external jobs, and remote database used by DBMS_SCHEDULER jobs, you need to use [DBMS_CREDENTIAL.CREATE_CREDENTIAL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/scheduling-jobs-with-oracle-scheduler.html#GUID-BCB91872-760D-43CA-A5E2-135C6A2DB2F5) procedure. [External procedures](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/managing-security-for-application-developers.html#GUID-EE267659-48F3-4AFA-BB06-D8C620F80696) are also using DBMS_CREDENTIAL.CREATE_CREDENTIAL.

The view [DBA_CREDENTIALS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_CREDENTIALS.html#GUID-69F7F819-1490-4260-A314-047B20BCBFB2) can be used for DBMS_SCHEDULER jobs and external procedures but not for database links.

There may be other resources that are using credentials in a different way.

Comment: Thanks! Here is a hypothetical use case-
Oracle 12 C database on windows under service acct  myad\ora1.  Another domain acct myad\acct1 has read access to a data file  \\myshare\file1.csv .
How do I create an external table in a user schema to the \\myshare\file1.csv without granting access to Oracle service account ?

Comment: In SQL Server you can create a credential to configure the file share and use the credential to access the file using a schema level stored procedure.

Comment: There are no credentials for external tables. It's the database instance that reads them using an database DIRECTORY object. I have no tested this on Windows but I assume that file .csv must be readable by the database service account. The Oracle user only needs grant on the DIRECTORY object (no privileges on the CSV file on Windows).